# How to not discard unchanged mails in mutt?

Tags: configuration, mutt

If I compose a new message, or reply to an existing message, mutt launches my editor. Then if I exit my editor with the mail unchanged mutt will discard the in-progress new mail or reply and drop me back to the mail folder view with "Abort unmodified message".  On the other hand, if I exit my editor with a change made (even if it is to save a new copy of exactly the same file, just to update the timestamp) then mutt takes me back to the "Compose" view.

Can I get the latter behaviour always?  It's very frustrating to type out a long list of email addresses only to lose them because of "Abort unmodified message".

Answer (score 1):

The desired behaviour can be obtained by adding the line `set abort_unmodified=no` to `.muttrc`.